# Laravel - combining routes by user type

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have a web app with 2 users types: admins and customers. In my users table I have a boolean column named "is_admin". When admins login, they should have access to one set of resources; when users login, they should have access to another set of resources.

I have a feeling I need to use either middleware or policies, but cannot find any good examples online.

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the code from my web.php routes file

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

    Route::resource('stock-types', 'StockTypeController');

    Route::resource('stock-items', 'StockItemController');

    Route::resource('companies', 'CompanyController');

    Route::resource('addresses', 'AddressController');

    Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactController');

    Route::resource('deliveries', 'DeliveryController');

    Route::resource('settings', 'SettingController', ['only' => [
        'index', 'update',
    ]]);

    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
});
```

Comment: You need to add some code so we can help you.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code from my web.php routes file. The stock-items resource is the one that a user can access, the others are for admins.

Comment: `is_admin` is a custom way. Yes, it's possible, although you will have to manage everything yourself. The Laravel way would be to use a standard ACL approach with roles and permissions: http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-52-user-acl-roles-and-permissions-with-middleware-using-entrust-from-scratch-tutorialexample.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in an example for admin check

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/create-middleware-to-auth-admin-users?page=1

Comment: The links are not welcome as answers. Would be good to add details here, so it will be clear what you are talking about even if a link is broken.